# Segfault in my Linked List implementation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node_struct {
    int data;
    struct node_struct *next;
} node;

void push(node *top, int data) {
    node *new_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = top;
    top = new_node;
}

int main() {
    node *top = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    top->data = 1;
    printf("Set data of top node to: %d\n", top->data);

    push(top, 2);
    printf("Pushed 2 to top, top->next->data = %d\n", top->next->data);
}
```

The program segfaults at the 3rd last line (`push(top, 2);`) and I think on the line `top = new_node;`

I'm just learning C (pointers right now).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: On a side note, you did not initialize the `next` element of your `top` node (after allocating it). Set it to `NULL` to know that it's the last element of your list (since your push function pushes element on top of the list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you pass the pointer to the `top` element by-value, and then you try to set the pointer inside the function but there it's just a local variable and changes to it will not be visible outside of the function.

Pass the `top` pointer by reference instead, by using a pointer to the pointer:

```
void push(node **top, int data) {
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = *top;
    *top = new_node;
}

...

push(&top, 2);
```

---

An alternative is to return the new top from the function instead:

```
node *push(node *top, int data) {
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = top;
    return new_node;
}

...

top = push(top, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointer is passed by value to `push`. Hence, the change you did to `top` is not reflected in `main`. If you want to change `top` then pass the address of pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node_struct {
    int data;
    struct node_struct *next;
} node;

void push(node **top, int data) {
    node *new_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = *top;
    *top = new_node;
}

int main() {
    node *top = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    top->data = 1;
    printf("Set data of top node to: %d\n", top->data);

    push(&top, 2);
    printf("Pushed 2 to top, top->next->data = %d\n", top->next->data);
}
```

Here's the relevant [C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html).